# Why part of Kafka partition don't write messages

Tags: apache-kafka

The system functions fully, I have created 3 brokers, there is 1 producer and 3 consumers. The producer assumes information, everything is ok on his part. Zookeeper sees all 3 brokers, coordinates information between them, when any broker is disabled, it reassigns the partition leader, information continues to be recorded. There are 3 consumers, when you disable any other pickup message, this is also ok. But, the problem is that the recording goes only to 4 partitions out of 6 ( 1, 2, 4, 5) On partitions with numbers 0 and 3, information is not destroyed. At the same time, the messages do not stop, with the exception of everything that absorbs from the producer. Why these 2 partitions fall out - I don’t understand yet

I tried to disable brokers, switch and replace consumers, looked at the logs of brokers - seems normal, messages are written without loss

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't guarantee even distribution of records. If you just send record values with null keys, then messages will be round-robined across batches, but not per record due to the [StickyPartitioner](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-producer-improvements-sticky-partitioner/)

For records with keys, then there's possibility for Murmur2 hash collisions

Check your records more closely to see if data actually is consumed from the other partitions, don't just look at the unique partition number.